# Typo3: getting a list of available languages as ISO language codes

Tags: internationalization, typo3

I need to get the list of available languages as 2-letter ISO codes.

I know I can select from "sys_language" to get a list of defined languages, but these don't contain such an ISO code.

The table structure for "sys_language" is as follows:

```
 1  uid                 int(11)     UNSIGNED    AUTO_INCREMENT
 2  pid                 int(11)     UNSIGNED
 3  tstamp              int(11)     UNSIGNED
 4  hidden              tinyint(4)      UNSIGNED
 5  title   varchar(80) utf8_general_ci
 6  flag    varchar(20) utf8_general_ci
 7  static_lang_isocode int(11)
```

I've tried adding some languages through the backend admin interface by clicking on a flag, but while this adds another row to the sys_language table, I don't see how such a defined language could be transferred into a 2-letter ISO language code.

The closest thing are the 2 letter flag codes which are inserted into the "flag" field, but a flag can't really be converted to a language code (think of Switzerland which has 3 (actually I think even 4) official languages).

So, how can I get a list of 2-letter iso codes for installed/activated languages?

Greetings/Thanks

Comment: What does `static_lang_isocode` contain?

Comment: static_lang_isocode contains "0" for the languages I've created through the admin interface (and I don't see a way to specify a value for it using the admin interface).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the extension **static_info_tables** found at [1.]

This provides a complete list of all territories, countries, country zones (states, local government areas), languages, currencies as prefilled tables in your backend. Additionally it extends sys_language to easily select a relation to those tables.

Afterwards this relation might be queried with the means of your choice.

***Links***:

1. http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/static_info_tables

Comment: Thank you very much; this seems to be what I'm looking for. I'll check it out.

Answer (score -3):

I'm afraid I don't know anything about typo3, but a list of valid ISO 6391-alpha2 codes (amongst others) can be found in this repo : https://github.com/tigrish/iso